# Confusion about how quantum operators can be expressed

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, atomic-physics

I'm studying atomic physics as one of my physics modules for university and i'm really getting confused with the way operators can be expressed. Specifically when it comes to coupling in the spin-orbit interaction, my lecturer has put:

$$
\hat{L}^2 = L\left(L+1\right)
$$
and 
$$
\hat{S}^2 = S\left(S+1\right)
$$.

In his notes earlier when talking about angular momentum in quantum mechanics he states

$$
\hat{L}^2 = \iota\left(\iota +1\right)\hbar^2
$$

where $\iota$ is the angular momentum quantum number.

So my question is where is the Hbar in the equation:
$$
\hat{L}^2 = L\left(L+1\right)
$$

has he just left it out because its a constant? or is there a bit of theory i am missing?

any help would help cheers

Comment: Are you *sure* there's a hat over both sides of the equation, and it's not $\hat{L}^2 = l(l+1)$ or $\hat{L}^2 = \ell (\ell +1)$?

Comment: yes sorry that is correct what you wrote i shall edit mine now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orbital and spin orbital energy, because we  are dealing with the discrete measurement involved in quantum mechanics,  have their values measured in either Planck constant $h$ or reduced  $ \hbar$. http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qangm.html is a good reference for this. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_units provides the values associated with $h$, which is known as an action.

To avoid making equations longer than they need to be, we can set these values to 1, and put them back in at the end of the calculations.

Comment: And thank you also. It's mainly to cut out h bar scribbles  ( in my writing anyway), also c = speed of ligh t= 1 and then left out. **Until the End**, otherwise you might lose exam marks if you forget to put them back in, or you need to show the dimensions are equal on both sides.   (Natural Units)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units] is worth a quick read for other units that are commonly set to unity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, he put $\hbar=1$ which is a fairly common thing to do in QM.